# Postgresql. Выбрать данные из таблицы с фильтром на дату

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица, из которой нужно выбрать имя, id и количество использований(name, id, uses) исходя из сегодняшней даты. Дата хранится в столбце last_seen в формате `2021-11-03 11:01:33.000000`.
Пробовал делать так:

```
SELECT id, full_name, uses, last_seen From users_new WHERE last_seen=localtimestamp(0)::timestamp::date Order by id'
```

Получаю пустой вывод, хотя командой отдельно от запроса дату вытащить можно.

Результатом нужно получить список пользователей, которые пользовались сегодня

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT id, full_name, uses, last_seen 
from users_new 
where last_seen::date = current_date
order by id;
```